# how to deploy a simple dart webService to apache server?

Tags: apache, dart

I have a very simple dart webService and i would like to deploy it to apache webServer.

```
#import('dart:io');
void main() {
  HttpServer server = new HttpServer();
  server.listen('127.0.0.1', 8080);

  server.defaultRequestHandler = (HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response){
 // response.outputStream.write("hello World".charCodes());
 // response.outputStream.close(); 

    File f = new File("test.txt");
    //File f = new File("index.html");
    f.exists().then((bool exist){
      f.openInputStream().pipe(response.outputStream);
    });
  };
}
```

When you call with GET 127.0.0.1:8080 from your browser, it reads a file test.txt and shows output in your browser.

How do i deploy that to an apache webserver somewhere online?

Comment: Because your code above works fine in the stand-alone Dart VM, can you clarify why you want to "deploy it to apache webServer" ? That might help us answer the question more accurately. Thanks!

Comment: I have few webservices running on django (vm with ubuntu) and others on webApi(IIS). I would like to setup a new VM ubuntu server, install apache webserver and just run simple dart webservices. The user should be able to send data with HTTP POST or GET and also receive data (xml or json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mod_dart (https://github.com/sam-mccall/mod_dart).

Comment: that was my fear. i hoped for something new

Comment: mod_dart is now dead project. (For anyone reading this in 2012)

Answer (score 4):

mod_dart might work, but you can also run Apache as a proxy in front of your Dart server. Many deployments of node.js have a proxy in front for load balancing, caching, etc. This same technique applies to Dart.